# Celery task result cannot get update_state and result using Flask with wsgi and Apache on AWS EC2 but it works fine on local Flask dev

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, celery

I am building a website with a task which takes quite a long time to process and needs heavy calculation. I wrote the code so that the task can give partial output (yield result). I use celery worker to run the task in another machine and set a task to send update using `update_state()`.

My `celery_tasks.py` file is something like this

```
@celery.task(name="my_task")
def my_task():
    final_output = []
    for output_part in long_process():
        my_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"progress": output_part})
        final_output.append(output_part)
    return final_output
```

In Flask, I create a route for SSE so that the front end can receive the part of output as soon as it is done. I wrote two routes - one for generate a task and another for receive the result stream.

```
@app.route('/gen-task', methods=['POST'])
def gen_task():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = my_task.apply_async()
        return make_response(jsonify({"task_id": r.id}), 200)

@app.route('/task-output-stream/<task_id>')
def task_output_stream(task_id):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery)
    def generate_stream():
        while not task.ready():
            print(f'State={task.state}, info type={type(task.info)}')
            info = task.info
            if info:
                output_part = info['progress']
                json_data = json.dumps({'output': output_part})
                yield f"data:{json_data}\n\n"
            time.sleep(2)
    return Response(generate_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

I test the flask app on my local machine (MacOS terminal). The task result is sent to the front end every 2 seconds as expected.
The flask log is something like this:

```
State=PENDING, info type=<class 'NoneType'>
State=PENDING, info type=<class 'NoneType'>
...
State=PROGRESS, info type=<class 'dict'>
State=PROGRESS, info type=<class 'dict'>
...
```

However, I try to deploy my flask app on EC2 but `task.info` is always `None` and `task.state` is always `PENDING`. I check the celery worker and the task runs fine and is finally finished but the web server cannot retrieve the update and result. Therefore, there is no event to the front end.

So, I wrote another test api for celery task and it can get the task result just fine on EC2. The task.ready() is `True`

```
@app.route('/get-task', methods=['POST'])
def get_task():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = my_task.apply_async()
        output = r.get()
        print('task.ready()', r.ready())
        return make_response(jsonify({"output": output}), 200)
```

For my celery setup, I use RabbitMQ as a broker and RPC as a backend.

What could be the cause of this issue? And how can I fix it?

Update: I replace RPC backend with Redis backend and it can now work as expected. I think it is the issue comes from the limitation of RPC backend.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer:

You need to add the `bind = True` argument to the celery decorator.
This instructs Celery to send a `self` argument to `my_task` function.
The `self.update_state()` call is how Celery receives task update.

#### Detailed answer:

Celery tasks always have a state. If a task finished executing successfully, its state is `SUCCESS`. If a task execution resulted in an exception, its state is `FAILURE`. Celery knows six [built-in states](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#built-in-states):

- `PENDING` (waiting for execution or unknown task id)
- `STARTED` (task has been started)
- `SUCCESS` (task executed successfully)
- `FAILURE` (task execution resulted in exception)
- `RETRY` (task is being retried)
- `REVOKED` (task has been revoked)

In case you wonder why you have never come across the `STARTED` state, it is not reported by default. You have to enable it explicitly via the Celery config, setting `task_track_started = True`.

###### The update_state method

The Celery task object provides an `update_state` method. This method lets you do three things:

- set the task’s state to one of the built-in states
- provide additional meta data
- set the task’s state to any custom state you define.

All you need to define your own state is a unique name. It is just a string and does not need to be registered anywhere. For example, if you have a long running task, you can define a `PROGRESS` state and publish the progress made via the `meta` json argument:

```py
import time
from worker import app

@app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
    n = 30
    for i in range(0, n):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'done': i, 'total': n})
        time.sleep(1)

    return n
```

This task runs for ~30 seconds and sends a task state update every ~1 second, broadcasting a custom `PROGRESS` state and the number of total and completed iterations. Let’s execute the task asynchronously, wait for the task to finish and capture the state and meta data while it’s still running:

```py
import time
import tasks

task = tasks.task.s().delay()

while not task.ready():
    print(f'State={t.state}, info={t.info}')
    time.sleep(1)

print(f'State={t.state}, info={t.info}')
```

Which produces something like this:

```bash
State=PENDING, info=None
State=PROGRESS, info={'done': 0, 'total': 30}
State=PROGRESS, info={'done': 1, 'total': 30}
State=PROGRESS, info={'done': 2, 'total': 30}
State=PROGRESS, info={'done': 3, 'total': 30}
...
State=SUCCESS, info=29
```

This is a very simple example. But if we take a closer look, there are a few very interesting learnings:

- any string can be a custom state
- a custom state is only temporary and is eventually overriden by a Celery built-in state as soon as the task finishes successfully - or throws an exception, is retried or revoked (the same applies if we uset `update_state` with a built-in state but custom meta data - the custom meta data is ultimatemy overwritten by Celery)
- while the task is in a custom state, the `meta` argument we published via `update_state` is available as `info` property on the `AsyncResult` object (the object `.delay()` returns on the execution side)
- when the task is in the built-in `SUCCESS` state, the `info` property returns the task result (when the task failed, the `info` property returns the exception type and stacktrace, try it yourself by throwing an exception in the implementation of the `task` function above)

#### Warm recommendation:

Too good tutorial and great explanation: [blog.miguelgrinberg.com - Using Celery With Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)